# No LuaRocks module found for 'bit'

Tags: lua, ubuntu-18.04, bit, torch, luarocks

I am trying to run a code using torch7 and LUA and I get this error.

```
    usr/local/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'bit' not found: No LuaRocks module found for 'bit'
        no field package.preload['bit']
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/bit.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/bit/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/bit.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/bit/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/lib/lua/5.2/bit.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/lib/lua/5.2/bit/init.lua'
        no file './bit.lua'
        no file '/home/shaurovd/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/bit.lua'
        no file '/home/shaurovd/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/bit/init.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/bit.so'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/lib/lua/5.2/bit.so'
        no file '/usr/local/torch/install/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './bit.so'
        no file '/home/shaurovd/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/bit.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/local/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
        train.lua:16: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        ...ocal/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to install 'bit' locally in my profile as I don't have the write permission on the server (Ubuntu 18.04) I am working on using:

```
luarocks install --deps bit --local
```

But it shows: `Error: No results matching query were found.`

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think Torch normally requires LuaJIT, not Lua 5.2, that may be your problem

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking in the same direction.

Answer (score 2):

i solved it by running this command

```
luarocks install luaossl OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local/kong CRYPTO_DIR=/usr/local/kong
```

check this post here [github kong issue](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/8259)